# Delegate nil after setting it

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am using the delegate method but for some odd reason my delegate variable seems to be nil when I want to call the delegate method. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
protocol ProfileProtocol {
    func buttonTapped()
}

class ProfileView: UIView {

    var delegate: ProfileProtocol?

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        configure()
    }

    func setup() {        

        ...
    }


    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // delegate nil
        delegate?.buttonTapped()
    }

}
```

ProfileViewController (yes it conforms to ProfileProtocol):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    swipeableView.nextView = {
       createCardView()
    }
}

func createCardView() -> UIView {        
    let cardView = ProfileView(frame: swipeableView.bounds)
    cardView.delegate = self

    let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ProfileCardView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first! as! UIView
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.backgroundColor = cardView.backgroundColor
    cardView.addSubview(contentView)

    activeCardView = cardView
    return cardView
}

func buttonTapped() {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "profileToEmojiCollection", sender: self)
}
```

Whenever I tap the button in my ProfileView, my ProfileViewController should perform a segue, however the delegate method isn't even being called because delegate is nil when I tap the button

Comment: Unrelated, I assume your protocol must be defined as a `class` protocol. But make sure to define the `delegate` property to be a `weak` var, because as you've got it here, you'll have a strong reference cycle between the view controller and the view.

Comment: Also unrelated, make sure that your `viewDidLoad` calls `super.viewDidLoad()`. Perhaps you did but omitted it for the sake of brevity, but just in case...

Comment: I'm actually not 100% sure what a class protocol is, so I don't think I defined it as that. Also thanks for pointing out the viewDidLoad

Comment: In your edit you show the creation of the `contentView`, which you then added as a subview of `cardView`. But you still are not adding either one of these to the main view hierarchy. Are you sure it is `cardView.addSubview(contentView)` and not `view.addSubview(contentView)`?

Comment: I'm using this framework https://github.com/zhxnlai/ZLSwipeableViewSwift/blob/master/ZLSwipeableViewSwiftDemo/ZLSwipeableViewSwiftDemo/ZLSwipeableViewController.swift

Comment: I believe the framework is adding cardview as a subview of a "swipeableview" that is in my storyboard. The view is indeed showing up. I appreciate you helping me, maybe the problem is more rooted in the framework I'm really not sure

Comment: I added a "zlswipeableview" to the storyboard. The zlswipeable uses "cards" which is my custom ProfileView class and they get added to zlswipeable view.

Comment: There must be some critical part that you haven't shared with us. For example, that `ZLSwipeableView` has an programmatic interface by which you could specify what subviews are shown in the `ZLSwipeableView`. But you aren't doing any of that above. You dont show us using any of the programmatic API for your `ZLSwipeableView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164902/discussion-between-brejuro-and-rob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to keep my custom views modular, and do things programmatically, it avoids the use of a Xib.

You should keep your view's responsibilities and subviews to the view itself. Ultimately the View receiving the the action(s) should be responsible for calling the delegate's methods. Also `nextView` is a closure that returns a UIView: `(() -> UIView?)?` not a UIView, a call to a function in a closure is not an explicit return you should return the view: `let view = createCardView() return view`.

**ProfileView.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol ProfileProtocol {
    func buttonTapped()
}

class ProfileView: UIView {

    var delegate: ProfileProtocol?


    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Profile Button", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return button
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {

    }


    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Check for a nil delegate, we dont want to crash if one is not set
        if delegate != nil {
            delegate!.buttonTapped()
        } else {
            print("Please set ProfileView's Delegate")
        }
    }

    func setup() {
        //setup subviews
        self.addSubview(button)

        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}
```

You can create ProfileView's like any other UIView, but remember to set the Delegate of each of them after creation:

```
swipeableView.nextView = {
    let view = createProfileView() //set properties during creation?
    view.delegate = self 
    //set properties after creation?
    //view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return view
 }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ProfileProtocol {

    lazy var profileView: ProfileView = {
        let view = ProfileView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        profileView.delegate = self


        setup()
    }

    func buttonTapped() {
        print("Do Something")
    }


    func setup() {
        self.view.addSubview(profileView)
        profileView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        profileView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.7).isActive = true
        profileView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        profileView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image: Image of View Hierarchy]

Comment: Actually this line `delegate?.buttonTapped()` won't crash if the delegate is nil it will just do nothing because the delegate is marked as being optional.  There is no need to explicitly check for it being nil unless of course you want to flag up such a situation.

Comment: you are 100% correct, I'll edit my answer to reflect this.